# lifecycle hook OnInit load after html can't show data from REST api in Forms?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typescript, angular2-services

[1]This is my Component

```
import 'rxjs/add/operator/switchMap';
import { Component, OnInit }      from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute, Params } from '@angular/router';
import { Location }               from '@angular/common';
import {TaskService} from '../../services/task.service';
import {Task} from '../../../Task';
@Component({
    moduleId: module.id,
    selector: 'detail',
    templateUrl: 'detail.component.html'
})

export class DetailComponent implements OnInit  {
    taskDetail: Task ;
    bankName:string;

    constructor(
        private taskService:TaskService,
        private route: ActivatedRoute,
        private location: Location
    ){
        this.getTask();
    }


    ngOnInit(): void {
        this.getTask();
        }


    getTask(){
        this.route.params.switchMap((params:Params) => this.taskService.getTask(params['id']))
            .subscribe(task => { console.log(task.title),this.taskDetail = task} );
    }
```

My Html

```
{{taskDetail?.title}}
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="textinput">Name</label>
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <input  [(ngModel)]="taskDetail.title" name="title" type="text"  class="form-control input-md">
        </div>
    </div>
```

Service:

```
  import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
    import {Http, Headers} from '@angular/http';
    import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
    import {Task} from "../../Task";

    @Injectable()
    export class TaskService{
        constructor(private http:Http){
            console.log('Task Service Initialized...');
        }

        getTask(id){
           return this.http.get('/api/task/'+id).map(res => res.json());

        }

    acceptData(){
        console.log(this.taskDetail);
}
```

Output:
Object {_id: "58f88cdacbdd7d24203d8ca8", title: "test", CreateDate: "2017-04-20", CurentMoney: "12312", isDone: false}

Error is EXCEPTION: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Error in http://localhost:3000/app/components/detail/detail.component.html:9:24 caused by: Cannot read property 'title' of undefined.

I think my problem is that , the data is not in the taskdetails when html tries to load them. I am loading them on ngOnInit. Is that ok? I think error is that title is not enable , but afteret this error, console.log from ngOnInit return me right value. I have made the function which return taskdetails.json and it's output is correct.

Image of error chrom:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MJm6Q.jpg)

UPDATE

```
   <input id="textinput"  value="{{taskDetail?.title}}" name="title-task" type="text"  class="form-control input-md">
```

This is working so the data is working good but when i change it to this, it is giving me error:

```
       <input id="textinput" [(ngModel)]="taskDetail.title"name="title-task" type="text"  class="form-control input-md">
```

**SOLUTION!!!**

Initialisation as empty object `task Detail:Task = <Task>{};` like this and now working. Thanks For Help.

```
<input id="textinput" [(ngModel)]="taskDetail.title"  name="title-task" type="text"  class="form-control input-md">
```

Comment: this may not be related but you have used a comma instead of a semi-colon in the subscribe call of your component

Answer (score 2):

You are calling the service on initialisation of the component but you haven't necessarily received a response and so given a value to your class property (`this.taskDetail`). The component is complaining about this as you're trying to bind, using ngModel, to a property of an undefined variable - instead you can either:

1) assign the variable initially to some blank/empty/placeholder value at the top of the component, or

2) you can use the "elvis" operator (`?.`) in the template:

```
<input  [(ngModel)]="taskDetail?.title" name="title" type="text" class="form-control input-md">
```

3) or you can make the display of the div wrapping the input conditional using `<div *ngIf='taskDetail'><input></div>`

EDIT: I would stick with method 3, personally:
[Plunkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/q5ZyVP3oNznDXoKkCip8)

Comment: 2)when i use "elvis" i got a big error and no compalable app:
Unhandled Promise rejection: Template parse errors:
Parser Error: The '?.' operator cannot be used in the assignment at column 19 in [taskDetail?.title=$event] in DetailComponent@9:24 ("l-label" .....
When i use 3) *ngIf directive i have lost the input value because it is null.
It is look that the response comes before html is load.
When i make Hardcode object taskDetail = {_id: "58f88cdacbdd7d24203d8ca8", title: "test", CreateDate: "2017-04-20", CurentMoney: "12312", isDone: false}; its working well .

Comment: why do you lose the input value with ngIf?

Comment: It is not solving the problem because it's only hide the input. I don't know why , it's not load at first on OnInit.

Comment: the input should only remain hidden while the component is waiting for the response - as soon as the response comes (and there;s no error), the input and the div around it will pop into view

Comment: because it's comes as empty.

Comment: Look at the image on the last line of my topic.

Comment: do you have a plunkr of this?

Comment: No it's full MEAM app . This json comes from express , but it'slook like it comes after HTML render:(

Comment: you can (almost) never assume your data will be available at component (view) render time - you should always allow for it to be delayed, coming in after render time, somehow!

Comment: Hmm yes this is true i coud be loaded after fiew secoind . But it is not happend i have to look Why.

Comment: I made a plunkr, check it out

Comment: Thanks i Updated some datas looks good and {{taskDetails | json}} giving nice JSON ;/